# KeepassX on 16.10 disabled the http option

Tags: 16.10, keepassx

I installed the latest ubuntu on a computer and I noticed that keepassX doesnt have the http option activated, whereas on ubuntu 16.04 it does.

The versions are exactly the same: 2.0.2 --> 3679b2170142c14362fa75e990ef85b80b1b1b46

Is there something I am missing? This option is the most important as it allows a communication between the application and the internet browsers, and it auto-fill the password.[image: The missing option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that I was using a fork of keepass on my other computer from here: 
https://github.com/eugenesan/keepassx

keepassx is still maintained but the feature I was looking for (the keepasshttp integration) as yet to be merged (> 3 years old) -> https://dev.keepassx.org/issues/91 (there even is a PR: https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx/pull/111)

So if you are looking for a keepassx with keepasshttp support, you can get the version from eugenesan's ppa: https://launchpad.net/~eugenesan